# CSS margin top not working

Tags: html, css

I have this CSS code:

```
 .tab-box {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #666666;
    padding-bottom:5px;
 }

.tab-box a {
  border:1px solid #666666;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
  text-decoration:none;
  background-color: #eee;
  background:#666666;
  color:#FFFFFF;
 }

.tab-box a.activeLink { 
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  color:#666666;
  border-bottom: 0; 
  padding: 5px 15px;
 }

.tabcontent {
    padding: 5px;
    width: 99%;
 }

.hide { display: none;}

.small { 
    color: #999; 
    margin-top: 100px; 
    border: 1px solid #EEE; 
    padding: 5px; 
    font-size: 9px; 
    font-family:Calibri; 
}
```

I am trying to add a margin top to the links.

I have tried adding `margin-top:30px;` to `.tab-box a` but it's not adding it.

I need it so if the tabs altogether are bigger than then screen width when they go below each other they are not overlapping.

Here is a fiddle with the full code http://jsfiddle.net/5rZP8/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were applying it to the element `a` who is a child of `.tabLink`.

Instead, apply it to an `a` element containing the class `.tabLink`.

```
a.tabLink {
    margin-top: 30px;
}
```

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/5rZP8/) - it works.

Additionally, you would also need to add `display:inline-block` in order for the margins to take effect.

Comment: I was gonna answer this but you are faster. +1

Answer (score 1):

**a** Elements by default are displayed as inline. So in order for the margin to take effect needs this.

In this way the browser will apply margin and padding attributes to the anchor.

http://jsfiddle.net/5rZP8/6/

I updated it so you can see it working.

```
.tabLink {
    margin-top:30px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see accepted answer to this question: [display:inline with margin, padding, width, height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5699967/displayinline-with-margin-padding-width-height). A link `a` is an inline HTML element and in CSS will be displayed as `display: inline` by default. A different value for `display` property will render differently.

Excerpt:

> Please see "[Inline formatting contexts](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#inline-formatting)" at the CSS spec for the full explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Inline elements don't work that well with margins. Adding `display: inline-block;` seems to work:

```
.tab-box a {
  border:1px solid #666666;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
  text-decoration:none;
  background-color: #eee;
  background:#666666;
  color:#FFFFFF;

  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5rZP8/2/

Answer (score 0):

The links need to be block elements for your code to work. Use this to make them block level elements while still preserving their other styling:

```
.tab-box a { display: inline-block': }
```

Once the links are block elements the div will expand to fill them. So now you can simply add:

```
.tab-box { margin-top: 30px; }
```