# a:hover css doesnt work

Tags: html, css

I've got a problem with some css. I have 2 buttons, one is an href and one is a form. The hover works on the form button but not on the href button.

```
.ims-button, .ims-button a:link, .ims-button a:visited {
    background-color: rgb(255, 204, 0);
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #999999;
    font-family: Ubuntu, Arial, "Arial Unicode MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 5px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    margin-left: 4px;
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.ims-button:hover, a.ims-button:hover, .ims-button a:hover {
    background-color: rgb(255, 204, 0);
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: none;
    font-family: Ubuntu, Arial, "Arial Unicode MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 4px 0 0 4px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

I cannot see why the href isnt working.

The site: http://goo.gl/pl7DFR
Once on the site, under the grey box with the photo in you can see the Add to cart link - click that and you'll see the 2 buttons - Checkout doesnt work, Add to Basket does...

Any ideas?

Comment: Please cut down on the amount of css you're posting here, and post the relevant html.  Most people aren't going to follow your link and wade through your source code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're attempting to apply margin to an inline (the "a") element, which isn't possible. Change the checkout link to

```
display: inline-block;
```

and you'll get quite a bit closer to what you're expecting.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/5700058/2517689 for more information on inline behavior.

Comment: Also add `line-height: normal` after applying `display: inline-block`.