# Anchor Tag (which is inline by default) not respecting margin bottom property of immediate neighbor above it. Why is that?

Tags: css

Simple fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/7frtbhpg/12/

Above is a very simple landing page (without using display:flex). The a tag is styled as a button :

```
#showcase a {
        /* display: inline-block; */
        margin-top:20px;
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
        background-color: #28a745;
        padding: 13px 40px;
        border-radius: 10px;
      }
```

I noticed that once i comment out the display:inline-block property of the 'a' tag, then it is respecting its padding and not respecting its margin-top property which is expected.

But additionally it is also not respecting the margin-bottom property of the element just above it. Why is that ?

Edit :  the padding of 'a' tag was overlapping with the margin-bottom of the element above it .So it gave the impression that the margin-bottom property is not working, but it actually is working because the 'a' tag moves down once the margin-bottom is increased.

Comment: *it is also not respecting the margin-bottom property of the element just above it.* --> it does, change it and you will notice your element moving. You need to understand that its effect will start from the top of the text since padding of the link will have no effect (I hope you get the image). If you remove padding from the link you will clearly see the margin

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5699967/displayinline-with-margin-padding-width-height

Comment: Does this answer your question? [display:inline with margin, padding, width, height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5699967/displayinline-with-margin-padding-width-height)

Comment: @Temani Yes, the padding of 'a' tag was overlapping with the margin-bottom of the element above it .So it gave the impression that the margin-bottom property is not working. Thanks again :).

Comment: @Temani increasing the margin-bottom of the element just above it does push the 'a' tag beneath it down. But how come the margin-bottom of one element is overlapping with the padding-top of 'a' tag beneath it ? This should not happen normally ..

Comment: because the padding of inline element doesn't affect the layout as you have discovered so it will overlap everthing including margin and even content